# How to get parent Node from Child category in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, tree

I have part of structure database from my projects, in this case I want to create Tree from my categories that only have variant .

this is my database sturcture

[image]

there are categories table that have name and slug , and categories group table because I have more than one kind of category , also category_rel_variant for relationship with another object(in my case is variant)

my goal is Display categories that have variant and restructure that Tree . 
example

categories

```
| id | name | slug | partition | 
| 1  | Animal | animal | null |
| 2  | monkey   | monkey | null |
| 3  | Fruit   | fruit | null |
| 4  | apple    | apple  | null |  
| 5  | Banana   | banana | null |
```

categories group

```
| id | cat_id | groups | description | parent | count |
| 1  | 1      | variant | animal variant | 0 | 0 |
| 2  | 3      | variant | fruit variant | 0 | 0 |
| 3  | 4      | variant | apple | 3 | 0 |
| 4  | 2      | variant | monkey | 1 | 0 |
| 5  | 5      | variant | banana | 3 | 0 |
```

categories_rel_variant

```
| id | cat_group_id | variant_id | sort |
| 1  | 5            | 1 | 1 |
| 2  | 1            | 2 | 2 |
```

variant

```
| id | name | {ect}
| 1  | green Banana is nice fruit
| 2  | there are monkey
```

when I try to query using this

```
    SELECT gp.id AS  'id_cat_group', gp.cat_id AS  'fk_cat_id', gp.parent, gp.groups, cat.id AS  'cat_id', cat.name
FROM categories_groups gp
LEFT JOIN categories cat ON ( gp.cat_id = cat.id ) 
LEFT JOIN categories_rel_variant crv ON ( gp.id = crv.cat_group_id ) 
LEFT JOIN variant vr ON ( crv.variant_id = vr.id ) 
LEFT JOIN categories t4 ON ( gp.parent = t4.id ) 
WHERE gp.groups =  'variant_category'
AND crv.variant_id
IN ( 1, 2 ) 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

that just give me current categories that have variant. my problem is I can't still get parent of that category.

from that result of quesry i want to re build tree to be like this

```
array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["name"]=>
      string(1) "Fruit"
      ["sub_category"]=>
       array(2) {
          ["id"]=>
          string(1) "5"
          ["name"]=>
          string(23) "Banana",
          ['variant'] => {--- array variant(ect) ---}

        }
    }
```

and soon ..

Any suggestion How to make like I mean ?

Comment: As an aside, I would strongly advice you to not use those awful alias names and don't use table aliases unless you query them twice.

Comment: I see you have edited your question with part of my answer in it; however, you forgot to also SELECT the corresponding fields, i.e. `SELECT t4.name AS subcat_name ...`

Comment: Can there be multiple generations (parent, child, grandchild, etc.) in the tree? I.e. Can Banana, which has Fruit as its parent, also have children (type of bananas)? If so, is there a limit to the number of generations (parent, child, grandchild, etc.) that are supported? Also, if so, what would the expected result look like with 3 generations being fetched? OR - is that what variant is supposed to reflect (grandchildren)?

Comment: can anyone give me sample ?

Comment: Instead of downvoting my answer, you could explain why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: it's  not clear and make me not understood correcty, can you explain more deep, like result from query from your answer, and the better format to do my goal ?

Comment: If you didn't understand, then why did you copy part of my query into your question? The idea is that you join the existing results with the categories table again to load the parent category details.

Comment: from that I just get empty result, ok for easy understood forget my query , what do you think and what should I do if I want to be generate result from my expectation ? 

please explain what format should I do for result like that form database query ? , whatever query code .

maybe it's not just one process , so I m very thanks you if you can explain to me.

Answer (score 1):

To get the parent you have to perform another `LEFT JOIN` on the `categories` table:

```
...
LEFT JOIN categories t4 ON t0.parent = t4.id
```

*The question was edited based on the above, but the following is also important.*

Then adjust the `SELECT` to include fields from this new table alias:

```
SELECT ..., t4.name AS subcat_name ...
```